# rich tooltip not updating when hovering on rows in datatable

Tags: datatable, richfaces

I have a datatable and I want to show a rich tooltip while hovering over a column in table.

```
<t:column id="nameColumn">

                <a4j:outputPanel layout="block">
                        <rich:toolTip direction="bottom-right" showDelay="300"
                                    layout="block">
                                <a4j:actionparam name="index" value="#{child.index}"
                                        assignTo="#{tableBean.currentTableRowIndex}" />
                                <h:outputText value="#{tableBean.currentTableRowIndex}"/>
                        </rich:toolTip>
                        <h:outputText value="#{child.name}" id="childName"
                                        styleClass="gridCell" >
                        </h:outputText>
                </a4j:outputPanel>
            </t:column>
```

If I use mode="ajax" nothing is appearing in tooltip. Actually it should display the row number. It would be very nice if you could help me. This issue is in v3.3.3

Answer (score 0):

Pls ensure that your code is inside a form tag